How to go to the previous location I touched in VSCode?
I set alt+left and alt+right as the very highly voted thread told me, and I even deleted any other bindings to the same chords. It just jumps to places I don't understand.


and here is what clicking a bunch of times and then clicking alt+left a bunch of times actually does

I have no idea what logic is being followed, but it is definitely not what I was expecting.
I only want a standard "go to last place I touched" behavior on alt+left

I guess what you want is cursor undo/redo. The default of undo is ctrl + U, and redo has no binding.

Almost what I want. It seems to be limited to the same file. If I click on one file and then another, the history stops. I just want a full history of the last place I touched.
